# Simple C++ program to find the area of a circle

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

//function declaration:
double circleArea(double);

int main(){
    double rad1;
    double rad2;
    double ringArea;

    cout<<"plz enter number";
    cin>>rad1;
    cout<<"plz enter number";
    cin>>rad2;

    ringArea = circleArea(rad1)-circleArea(rad2);
    cout<<ringArea<<endl;

    system("pause");
}

// function definition:
double circleArea(double rah){
    return(3.1415926*rah*rah);
}
```

In above code if I enter 5 then it return value 2.66454e-015 **but if I make changes in function definition like**

```
double circleArea(double rah){
     int confuse;
     confuse =(3.1415926*rah*rah);
     return confuse;
}
```

and enter value of 5,5 or 6,6 or 7,7 then it return value of 0.but when I enter 5,6 or 6,7 other than same values then it return some other value which is not matching with part in which I have not declared variable confuse.

Comment: What was your intention when you stored the floating result in an integer variable?

Comment: i have no intentions i am just curious how the heck is that variable declaration making changes in program however i am not changing the values i have just made variable confuse and assign the values of function circleArea but it gives different results.

Comment: @DeiDei Would you instead suggest double confusion or float confusion?

Answer (score 1):

Your variable declaration is wrong

```
double circleArea(double rah){
     double confuse;
     confuse =(3.1415926*rah*rah);
     return confuse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try that

```
double circleArea(double rah) {
    double confuse;
    confuse = (3.1415926*rah*rah);
    return confuse;
}
```